# nHibernate Subquery-WhereAll displays "not a delegate type"-error

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am trying to create a nHibernate-Query with a subquery following this [blog-entry](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/10/24/queryover-series-part-8-working-with-subqueries/).

My working SQL looks like this:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Product
  WHERE Id IN (
      SELECT p.Id
      FROM Product AS p
      INNER JOIN ProductSupplier AS ps
      ON ps.ProductId LIKE p.Id
      WHERE ps.SupplierProductNumber LIKE '102.02-7100'
      GROUP BY p.Id
  );
```

I have to group by the Id because multiple suppliers can have the same `productNumber` for the same product.

My `nHibernate` looks as following:

```
query.WithSubquery.WhereAll(
    p => p.Id ==
        QueryOver.Of<Product>()
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Suppliers, () => productSupplierAlias)
        .Where(() => productSupplierAlias.Product.Id == productAlias.Id)
        .Where(() => productSupplierAlias.SupplierProductNumber == searchtext)
        .Select(p => p.Id));
```

But my `.Select(p => p.Id)` displays

> cannot convert lambda expression to type 'nHibernate.Creterian.IProjection[]' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be using `WhereAll` in this case.

Does this work:

```
query.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(p => p.Id)
                    .In(QueryOver.Of<Product>()
                         .JoinAlias(x => x.Suppliers, () => productSupplierAlias)
                         .Where(() => productSupplierAlias.Product.Id == productAlias.Id)
                         .Where(() => productSupplierAlias.SupplierProductNumber == searchtext)
                         .Select(p => p.Id)
                    );
```